# First ODEs Nonlinear Polynomial

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, nonlinear-system

I have the following system of nonlinear polynomial differential equations:

$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{dx(t)}{dt}=-3y(t)-3m(2p+x(t)^2-8y(t)^2) \\
\dfrac{dy(t)}{dt}=ex(t)+6mx(t)y(t) \\
\dfrac{dz(t)}{dt}=1+kp + \frac{3}{4}e - 6my(t)
\end{cases}$

where $m$, $e$, $p$ and $k$ are constant parameters.

I know that the third equation can not be separated and resolved later by quadrature since $z(t)$ is not present in the first two equations.

The biggest problem is certainly the strong non-linearity in the second equations.

Can anyone tell me how they can solve or the method to solve the first two equations.

Thanks in advance to everyone:)

Comment: "I know that the third equation can not be separated" - did you actually mean "can be separated"?

Comment: Do you want an exact solution? Or will a numerical one be enough? Aslo, what are the initial conditions?

Comment: There  is a theory of "Differential  Galois  Theory" which convinces us  that almost  all  nonlinear  equation  can not be  solved in term of  quadrature.  So  even in the  case  that  the  non linear  term  has  degree 2, a  generic  equation can be  solved in term of  elementary  solutions.

Comment: 1) the third quation can be solved separately by quadrature because the variable $ z (t) $ is not present in the other two equations
2) I.C. are generic $ x (0) = x_0 $ and $ y (0) = y_0 $ (at most you could impose $ x (0) = 0 $)
3) for "numerical solution" what do you mean? use an iterative algorithm?

Comment: @MatteoNicoli, I meant any numerical scheme for integrating a 1st order system of ODEs. There are dozens of them. That's how most ODEs are solved these days. Euler scheme as the most simple.

Comment: @AliTaghavi, did you mean "a generic equation can NOT be solved in term of elementary functions"?

Comment: @YuriyS  Yes. There  are  a  lot  of  elementary  equations  which can  not  be  solved in terms of  elementary  functions. A popular example  is  $\begin{cases} x'=y-x^2\\ y'=-1 \end{cases}$.  This  equation is  discussed in several references  for  example  a  book  on Diff. equation by  John  Hubbard."Diff.  Galois  Theory" is  devoted to  such  pathological situations.

Comment: See for example here about numerical methods for nonlinear ODEs https://hplgit.github.io/num-methods-for-PDEs/doc/pub/nonlin/pdf/nonlin-4print.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The first two equations fall into the class of projective Riccati equations, the analysis of which goes back to Lie and Vessiot.
Refer Robert L Anderson, "A Nonlinear Superposition Principle Admitted by Coupled Riccati Equations of the Projective Type", Letters in Mathematical Physics **4** (1980) pp. 1-7.